# SharePoint 2010 Farm Shutdown Procedure

Tags: administration, server-farm

What is the recommended procedure for shutting down a SharePoint 2010 Farm? In other words, after I have quiesced the farm, what additional steps do I need to take to ensure that there is NO SharePoint-related activity on the farm? I know how to quiesce the farm, and how to stop the SharePoint services via the Windows Services on a single-server installation, but I am trying to determine how best to shut down all the SharePoint services across a medium-sized farm with multiple WFEs, multiple app servers, and multiple database servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to completely stop a SharePoint farm there is a useful list of services within the [Move all databases (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723.aspx#Stop) article.

Obviously (as you have requested) this will mean that ALL SharePoint activity will cease:

"To stop the farm
On the server that is running the Central Administration Web site, in the Services snap-in, stop the following services:

SharePoint 2010 Administration

SharePoint 2010 Timer

SharePoint 2010 Tracing

SharePoint 2010 User Code Host

SharePoint 2010 VSS Writer

SharePoint Foundation Search V4

World Wide Web Publishing Service

On the server that is running the Central Administration Web site, at the command prompt, type iisreset /stop."

Answer (score 3):

What is it that you hope to accomplish by taking SharePoint offline?

Quiescing the farm will prevent SharePoint from serving end-users so you can install features and so forth.

Stopping the services goes another step beyond that. In fact, you will not be able to install features if all of the SharePoint services have been stopped.

The procedure is the same when there are multiple servers. You would just need to stop the services on all the machines.

Aside from shutting down the SQL Server instance and actually shutting down the Windows Servers that all your farm servers are running on, I cannot think of anything else that you would need to do.

Comment: This is pretty much it, once you quiesce the farm, and all the workflows & whatever have finished running, you're free to switch off the services and repurpose/format/whatever your servers.

Comment: @Rob - you indicate that quiescing the farm will allow administrators to install features etc; what additional steps are necessary to ensure that there is NO SharePoint-related activity on the farm? (I should perhaps clarify that I would still want Windows running.) Does it matter what order the SharePoint services are stopped in? Does it matter what order the servers are shut down in?

In answer to your question, the question arose in a discussion of backups with the team at my company that administers Windows servers.

Comment: So you are wanting to backup the Windows Server?  Stopping the services should do it then. It doesn't matter in what order you shut them down.